# Does Hibernate's createCriteria() sanitize input?

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-injection

Came across some code today that uses Hibernate to perform a query.  The query uses a value submitted from a form.  It made me curious as to whether or not this sort of code "sanitizes" its input.

```
public List<School> search(String query) {
    Session session = this.getCurrentSession();
    query = "%" + query + "%";
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
    criteria.createAlias("country", "a");
    Criterion nameCriterion = Restrictions.ilike("name", query);
    Criterion cityCriterion = Restrictions.ilike("city", query);
    Criterion countryCriterion = Restrictions.ilike("a.name", query);
    Criterion criterion = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.or(nameCriterion, cityCriterion), countryCriterion);
    criteria.add(criterion);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Is this safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hibernate Criteria Queries are quiet safe in terms of Sql Injection since they pass strings as parameter while performing any fetch. Even, Hql is quiet safe unless you build the query via string literal.

For more details, you should take a look at queries getting fired at the database level by switching on hibernate sql logging.

Comment: It so happens I was just looking at the generated SQL (which is what reminded me to check for these answers) and you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 5):

If you think to SQL injection attacks, then yes, Hibernate Criteria API is safe.

It will generate the underlying query by first compiling it from the specified query fields and only after apply the query parameters (It should use a classical `PreparedStatement`). This way the JDBC driver will know which part of the query are fields and which part are parameters. Then the driver will take care to sanitize the parameters.

Tough you should take care with the SQL restrictions applied on the `Criteria`, if you need to place parameters there. For example

```
String vulnerable = //parameter from user interface 

criteria.add(
    Restrictions.sqlRestriction("some sql like + vulnerable") //vulnerable

criteria.add(
    Restrictions.sqlRestriction("some sql like ?", 
              vulnerable, Hibernate.STRING)) //safe
```

In this case the `vulnerable` parameter could "leak" in to the query fields part and be bypassed by JDBC driver checking as in a normal vulnerable SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is useful to sanitizing inputs but sanitizing inputs is not considered the best practice for preventing SQL injection attacks. As your code develops over time, you will need to remember to change your Hibernate sanitation as your database and client-side application change; this leaves a lot of room for error and any one mistake can compromise your database.

To prevent SQL injection attacks, it is better to use prepared statements. In a prepared statement, your client-side application will make a non-SQL request and let your server generate your SQL statement.

For example, if a user wants all users in the city "Dallas" then your client-side application should make a request similar to *username equals "Dallas"* and then your server can generate:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='Dallas'
```